# Create a Verilog Parser with Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, verilog, parser-generator

I would like to create a Verilog parser written in Ruby for a university project

I know there are parser generators like Bison and Yacc.

Could anyone give me some advice on how to get started?

Comment: You haven't showed any attempt to provide a solution, which is expected on Stack Overflow. What searches have you done, or what code have you written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already have a very basic verilog parser (gem) written in ruby called [verilog](https://rubygems.org/gems/verilog), if you could consider contributing to that instead, or it might give an idea of how to start.

I also have a gem called [rubyit](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_it), which is command line utility to parse files with erb and generate the standard version of the file. Which can be used for extendable verilog templates, similar to generate statements but gives a flexible port list and ability to check the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

There do exist parser generators for Ruby too, e.g. [racc](https://rubygems.org/gems/racc). Start installing the racc gem and read the included documentation and examples.

Comment: [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/racc) seems to have the latest version (1.4.9) of racc vs the 1.4.6 version on [rubyforge](http://rubyforge.org/projects/racc/).